# Does Java compiler recognize byte and short as literals?

Tags: java, literals

What I actually meant to ask is, if I write :

```
byte b=13;
short s=14;
```

Then values on the right-hand side i.e., 13 and 14 respectively are treated as *byte* and *short* **Or** is just read as an *int* type by the compiler.
If they are read as bytes and shorts respectively then why,

```
byte b1=13;
byte b2=23;
byte b3=b1+b2;
```

And

```
short s1=14;
short s2=24;
short s3=s1+s2;
```

are *invalid* statements(short s3=s1+s2; and byte b3=b1+b2;) in java even if the the precision is not compromised in bothe the cases.

And if they are just read as *int* types by the compilers, then how their identity is maintained by the compiler for being *byte* or *short* types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have byte or short literals. What it does have is an [implicit assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) from int to byte, char and short when the int is a compile time constant and in range for the target type.

So, this is OK:

```
byte b = 13+14; // implicit conversion
```

But this is not:

```
void method(byte b) {}

method(13);
```

Nor this:

```
byte b = 13+nonConstant;
```

Answer (score 0):

You hav to cast the result of `+` which is an `int`.

```
byte b1 = 13;
byte b2 = 23;
byte b3 = (byte) (b1 + b2);

short s1 = 14;
short s2 = 24;
short s3 = (short) (s1 + s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because integer literals (and more generally constant expressions of type int) are handled specially by the compiler. When you assign an integer literal to a byte or short, the compiler checks if it is in the range of the target type and then allows the assignment without a cast.

Comment: Then why int i=12; byte b=i;, is an invalid statement even if the value of i is in the range of byte

Comment: Because `i` is not an integer literal.

Comment: If i is not an integer literal then what it means to be declaring int 1=12;?

Comment: `i` is a variable; `12` is a literal.